# VPS policy states CPU usage limitations

Tags: vps, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, cpu-usage, redis

I have found a cheap vps solution to cover my needs. Reading through the policies of the vps service, I found that they state "CPU usage should not exceed 70%". Is there a way to prevent this? I plan to run a rails application on that vps + postgres + redis and I have no way of knowing when cpu usage will exceed 70%. I mean, should you be concerned about this when you sign for a vps service? Is this normal or is it bad marketing or does it come from poor virtualization technology they may use?

Comment: Utilization is work over time. Do they specify the time period they are counting that from?

Comment: copied from their Terms of Service: "...It is not allowed to use more then 75% of CPU time or/and doing more then 100io operations for a long period of time (>6h)..."

Comment: You cannot honour the CPU requirement in its current form, its nonsense. Its the equivalent of saying "whilst travelling in your car, you should not exceed 75% speed".

Comment: Read between the lines and it says: we overcommit CPU and we need a stick to beat you with if your usage pattern has a negative impact on the other VPS's on the same host. Generally speaking overcommitting CPU is not necessarily bad and probably the reason for their low prices.

Comment: Thank you all for all your comments. I realized, that they compensate for the low price they charge with the strange policy the impose on their users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Is there a way to prevent this?
```

Potentially, install & configure 'cpulimit' package if possible.  Nice/renice might help.

```
should you be concerned about this when you sign for a vps service?
```

That TOS is ridiculous and puts burden of resource consumption monitoring on the user.  Any other company will give you X resources and you are allowed (at least try) to use them 100%, 24/7.

```
 Is this normal or is it bad marketing
```

It is not normal, even for cheap VPS providers.  Resource management should be done at the VPS level and it should not be something a user has to manage within the instance.  This is a bad policy and hints at issues with their infrastructure and service in general.

```
does it come from poor virtualization technology
```

To my knowledge, every virtualization platform allows you to configure guest resources.  The provider is either lazy, bad at their job, or is using the written policy as a way to bully users.

Comment: thanx. I was thinking of using cpulimit too but what would be the point of monitoring your own cpu limit for something you pay?. Anyway, they charge 100 us dollars / year for a 2 core cpu + 90 GB space with no backup plan.

Comment: @Nick_K That's not even a great price.  Take a look here: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=a6c687ca98131ae55e35f1dcc43cc6a8&f=104